# How to enforce linking an object module or symbol from a library in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

I have some legacy C++ code which I wan't to move to a (static) library (.lib).
However, the legacy C++ code uses constructors of global objects to do some initialization (pls don't discuss that this may be bad practice - it basically works and it its legacy code I don't want to change). This works as long as the global object becomes part of the .exe, which always happens if the source code and hence its .obj file, containing that global object, is part of the .exe project in visual studio (2008). If I move the module to the library, the linker will not include this module, since it is not referenced by any module of the .exe. So I need to enforce linking that module into the .exe

I know the linker cmd line option /INCLUDE, which I can also specify using #pragma comment(linker, "/iclude: ... "). However, there are some problems:

1. I need to specify the decorated name of the C++ object. I can work around this by some dummy extern "C" symbol such as an int, still not nice and there are a lot of them.
2. I either have to specify all symbols in the linker commandline (as I mentioned, there are a lot of them) or, if I use #pragma, the #pragma statement has to be part of some module of the .exe (or included as headerfile by such a module). It did not work to place the #pragma into the source code where the symbol is defined (in the library). So both ways enforce linking the symbols by the build process of the .exe (either by commandline or by sourcecode of the .exe) but not by the code of the library.

So what I'm looking for is a way in visual studio 2008 to enforce linking a module by definition of the module of the library like: "if library X.lib is specified as input of the linker, then module Y.obj of X.lib will always be linked into the .exe, regardless any references by other modules". Preferably not using decorated names.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm going to answer my own question. In fact it is another workaround.

The workaround is not a linker option but a VS setting, that only works if both, the .lib and the .exe are in the same solution and if the dependency of the .exe to the .lib is correctly sepcified in the solution settings.

In the "Linker Property Page" of the VS project of the .exe set "Use Library Dependency Inputs" to "Yes" so the .obj(s) of the .lib will be used instead the .lib as linker input. Since the linker includes all .obj(s) specified as input, whether referenced or not, the effect is similar to specifying all source modules of the .lib as part of the .exe project itself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/024awkd1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

One drawback is, that this setting is not .lib specific. It affects all dependent .libs in the solution (but not the libs specified as additional input). Check the linker commandline to know the effect.